# Regex that can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores, but the first character must be alphabetical (single character failure)

Tags: regex

I have the following regex pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]+$`
```

It is used to match; alphanumeric characters, underscores and dashes, with the first character being alphabetical.

This works as expected, but I also need it to be able to match single characters. A conditions of `a` fails.

How can I modify the pattern to make a single alphabetical character pass?

Comment: *\* (zero or more times)
+ (one or more times)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` means "one or more". Replace it with `*` for "zero or more".

Answer (score 4):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*$
```

This shoudl do it for you

Comment: Could you explain the significance of using `*` instead of `+`?

Comment: @S-K' `*` mean `0 or more` `+` means `1 or more`